# Initializing a ActionBarDrawerToggle with some confusing code

Tags: java, android

```
Android Studio 1.1 Beta 4
```

Hello,

I am expecting some source code below, and I can't understand the reason behind it. I can understand this part

```
 ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle =
                    new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close)
```

Creating a new instance of the ActionBarDrawerToggle with a constructor that takes 5 arguments.

The part this is confusing is why the braces after, I have never seen that before. Is this a shortcut of doing something?:

```
{
    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
    }
};
```

complete:

```
 private void init() {
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle =
                new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close) {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) implements [DrawerLayout.DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html) which has **abstract** methods. This means you have to define them.
ActionBarDrawerToggle does define them itself but you can overwrite them in `{}` after the constructor. Actually you are creating an anonymous subclass of ActionBarDrawerToggle. (A class without a name)

You can read about it in the [Java documantation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 1):

The given construction:

```
SomeType st = new SomeType(){
    ...
}
```

creates **anonymous subclass** extending `SomeType` and allows to override/add methods, add members, make initialization etc

In your case `{}` creates anonymous subclass extending `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and overriding methods `onDrawerOpened()` and `onDrawerClosed()`.

**P.S.** It's useful when you need class only once.